# Spawning command prompt app in CMD window in C#

Tags: c#

I need to run a legacy app that is run from a cmd window using the Process class.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C \"C:\\MySys\\My2Com.exe –r " + Parameters.FullPath;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

try
{
    // Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    string sMsg = "Error copying the files to " + Parameters.FullPath + ".";
    HandleErrorMsg(e, sMsg);
    return;
}
```

The process My2Com.exe should run in the background, however, I consistantly get the message that a file, used when run from the cmd line with different flags, is missing.  If I run the command as indicated in a cmd window, C:\MySys\My2Com.exe –r FullyQualPath, it works as expected. I have tried several different ways to set up the Process class without success.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't put a closing double-quote on your Arguments property. Is that deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C \"C:\\MySys\\My2Com.exe –r\" " + Parameters.FullPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

will this work if you do the following

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C "C:\MySys\My2Com.exe /r" " + Parameters.FullPath +"\"";
```

keep in mind that if there are spaces in the filepath you need to wrap around """ for example if the filepath were like this @"""C:\Wolf Lair\WorkDeskTemp\"

**notice the @ and the """**

you need to append the ending quotes to the string +"\""; after Parameters.FullPath;

Answer (score 0):

You know why is it not working because

- You haven't completed quotes

Try this:-

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C \"C:\\MySys\\My2Com.exe\" –r \"" + Parameters.FullPath+"\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C ""C:\MySys\My2Com.exe –r """ + Parameters.FullPath + "\"";
```

Also, see [Sending commands to cmd prompt in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767654/sending-commands-to-cmd-prompt-in-c-sharp/11768260#11768260). I'd recommended using some of the code from my answer there so that you can intercept the standard output and standard error to see what you're getting.