# How can I execute an Asynchronous command-line process from a windows form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, console-application

I have a Windows form application that currently executes NANT in a console application  to run our software build process. I'm looking for an example on how to execute console process (with command-line) asynchronously. I found a sample project on Asynchronous Design Patterns on the CodeProject website but it doesn't mention anything about console applications unless I'm not not understanding the concept they show.

I have a class that has a method called run with executes a console command (NANT.EXE) by shelling out.

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.Arguments = CreateNAntCommandLine();
si.FileName = m_Settings.NAntExe;
si.WorkingDirectory = m_Settings.CurDir;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = si;
bool bProcStarted = proc.Start();
```

Jim

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Starting processes (via new Process("yourExecutable.exe").Start() is already asynchronous

Comment: I have a class that has a method called run with executes a console command (NANT.EXE) by shelling out. <code> ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(); si.Arguments = CreateNAntCommandLine(); si.FileName = m_Settings.NAntExe; si.WorkingDirectory = m_Settings.CurDir; Process proc = new Process(); proc.StartInfo = si; bool bProcStarted = proc.Start(); </code>

Comment: Perhaps if you include the code you have now, it would help.

Comment: As aquinas said, starting a Process is already asynchronous until you call WaitForExit. You may want to have a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767654/sending-commands-to-cmd-prompt-in-c-sharp/11768260#11768260 for some example code.

Comment: Ok.. the code is in the above comment. Not sure why my code tags are not formatting it correctly.

Comment: Ok I thank you both. :)  I'll take a look at the example you mentioned in 11767654.

Comment: @JimMacDiarmid code tags won't work. You can enclose a block in \` to indicate code, but it still won't keep line breaks. If you want to add code, put it in your question and make sure that each line of code is preceded by at least 4 spaces or a tab character. I updated your question with your code from the comment for you.