# A method to execute cmd prompt command going wrong

Tags: c#, string

I have this method

```
private void _executeCommand(string commandStr, int timeout)
         {

            try
            {
               System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                   new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + commandStr);
               procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
               procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
               // Do not create the black window.
               procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
               // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
               System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
               proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
               proc.Start();
               Thread.Sleep(timeout);

            }
            catch (ExecutionEngineException e)
            {

               throw e;

            }}
```

somehow, if I pass a string called `myCmd`, `_executeCommand(myCmd, timeout)`, it does nothing. But if I pass the exact string value of `myCmd`, `_executeCommand("copy //data//file \"C://Program Files/myApp\"", timeout)`, it was able to execute. Could anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: So what isn't working I am confused ?

Comment: You pass in a string called `myCmd`, ok, so what's in it?!

Comment: Chances are `/c` is only expecting _one_ other argument, not a call with spaces. Try wrapping the command in quotes. (e.g. `cmd /c copy \data\file \dest\file` becomes `cmd /c "copy \data\file \dest\file"`) **EDIT** Never mind, it appears to be indifferent. Just tested it.

Comment: It all depends on how you initialize `myCmd`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a command that has its own arguments you want to execute using /c, you will need to enclose the entire command and its argument after /c in quotes. Further, if you're using a path that contains spaces as one of the arguments to your command you'll have to quote that too, i.e `@"/c ""copy ""C:\My Folder\Ny File.txt"" ""C:\My Other Folder"""""`

Also, If you have multiple commands that you want it to perform you will either have to put the commands in a batch file and execute that or enclose them in quotes and separate them with &&, i.e. `@"/c ""cd \ && dir"""`.

Note that the doubling of quotes in my examples is how you escape quotes when using a string literal in C#. The `@` preceding the string tells the compiler to take the string literally and not to interpret `\` characters as special.

Taking a look at my answer to [Sending commands to cmd prompt in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768260/1015164) is probably a good idea too as it explains a lot about how this stuff works.

Comment: Still not working, I added double quotes on every substring there. cmd line still could not execute it. But the same hard code string does get executed. very weird...