# Updating mainform's textbox control with string from DataReceivedEventHandler function?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using example from microsoft to handle stdout and stderr using async method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.datareceivedeventhandler?view=net-5.0

However, how do I update a text box's text property in the main form? Because, it disallow thread to update control in another thread. i.e, I want this handler below to update frmMain.txtBox1.text
to show stdout logs in text box.

```
    private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // Collect the sort command output.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            numOutputLines++;

            // Add the text to the collected output.
            sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine +
                $"[{numOutputLines}] - {outLine.Data}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768260/17034

Comment: Or just simply theProcess.SynchronizingObject = Application.OpenForms[0];

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `frmMain` is a valid instance (and points to the already showing form on your screen), and that `txtBox1` has had its modifiers property changed to public so it's visible, you can do something like:

```
frmMain.txtBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    // ... put code in here ...
});
```

If frmMain is literally the name of the TYPE of your Form, you need to get a reference to the actual instance of frmMain being displayed on your screen. There are various ways to do this, including iterating over the open forms, or possibly passing in that instance beforehand from somewhere else.